# Serviços corporativos na nuvem

Tags: javascript, java, python, html5, css3

O "avanço" da tecnologia em questão de serviços cloud, vai levar a WebServices na nuvem ao invés de uma rede privada da empresa X ou até mesmo rede local?

Comment: Na minha opinião, essa pergunta demanda respostas baseadas em opinião e assim foge do escopo definido para o site. Você pode ler o guia de [ask] e ver se consegue editá-la de acordo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ter webservices na nuvem/cloud tem vantagens e desvantagens:

**Vantagens:**

- não é necessário montar o sistema que:

  - precisa de espaço de armazenamento
  - precisa de segurança para integridade dos dados
  - precisa de ter backups e sistemas de manutenção e updates a funcionar

**Desvantagens:**

- por vezes alguns webservices têm ligações lentas por estarem em servidores remotos (longe demais)
- por vezes os dados que colocamos ou passam pelo webservice são abrangidos pela lei do país em que o servidor está e não o país da empresa que o corre
- por vezes os dados não são 100% conofidênciais, o Google e Dropbox (entre outros) têm acesso aos dados ainda que não os divulguém. Nem todas as empresas aceitam esta realidade.